# Table properties using SQL in Pervasive SQL control centre

Tags: pervasive-sql, actian

I wanted to retrieve table properties using pervasive sql control center.
Version 9.52

How can i retrieve all the tables properties from a Database ? i tried some thing like below for one table but it throwed me an error

```
select * from "TABLE NAME"
CALL psp_column_attributes (, ,)
```

error messgae :- Invalid procedure name

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you're installation doesn't have the system stored procedures.  You should be able to recreate them.  There should be a directory called `restore` under the `system` database directory.  I can't remember where is was in V9, maybe `c:\pvsw\demodata\system`.  I know that for v10 (and later), it is in `C:\ProgramData\Pervasive Software\PSQL\system\restore` or `C:\ProgramData\Actian\PSQL\system\restore`.

Comment: Hi mirtheil we dont have access to modify any paths. Is there any other way we can generate the DDL for the tables using pervasive?

Comment: I had joined X$FILE and X$FIELD and got the information , but the datatype was shown as 0 , 11, 1, ,..is there a mapping that 0 means character datatype ? if so  where can i get these conversions of datatypes.

Comment: There's not an automated way to map the data type number to a string value.  You can look for the psp_columns system stored procedure restore file for a big case statement that does it.